# Applying survey weights to data before compiling contingency tables in R

Tags: r, survey, contingency

The sample for a survey I am analysing was not selected randomly and so I need to apply a vector of weights to make the findings representative of the population. I have used `wtd.table()` (from gmodels) successfully to create frequency tables but now want to create a contingency table to compare two categorical variables and conduct a Chi-sqrd test. I'm struggling to find the right function. The `svytable()` function in the `survey` package sounds promising but I don't see where I should input the weight vector. I'm new to R. Could anyone explain how to use `svytable()` or suggest an alternative?

Comment: type ?svytable for some examples.  for more examples, play with the public use survey microdata syntax at http://github.com/ajdamico/usgsd